# Extract educational qualifications from someone's title via regex

Tags: php, regex

I need to write a regular expression which will filter education qualifications of people from a particular file.

For example :

```
B.Tech B.Com M.S S.S.C
```

I have been trying with the following code

```
if(strlen($data<=6))
{
  $regexp="/^[A-Za-z\.]$/";
  if(preg_match($regexp,$data))
  {
    echo 'Education = ' . $data .'<br />';
  }
}
```

But I only get the last dot and the character after it.

Comment: "but i only get the last dot and the character after it" --- it's not possible. Your regex can only match 1 char length string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `\b(([\w]+[.][\w]+)([.][\w])*)` Using this you can extract B.Tech, B.com, M.S .... so on from any string

Explanation [Here](http://www.regex101.com/r/rF2kI0)

Comment: `[.]` -> `\.`, `[\w]` -> `\w`

Answer (score 2):

How about `/.*/`? It would match your whole string - which is an education qualifications (like you wanted).

PS: you didn't bother explaining the whole string structure and additional criterias - so you get so generic answer.

Comment: this doesnt work either.. actually i want string that has length less than 6 and contains a dot in it..

Comment: @user1934120: "doesn't work" isn't an explanation. What have you tried? Hold your breath and give thorough and detail explanation of what you have and what you need in the question. Do that in a way like you're explaining it to a granny (it's not a joke)

Comment: if i want to extract B.Com from a file which has other data too.. then i need regular expression which extracts B.Com amongst other data. so i m not getting the output from my regular expression or urs either. now is it better explained

Comment: @user1934120: is it always "B.Com"?